# Jenkins ANT_OPTS works locally, but not globally

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am trying to set ANT_OPTS globally in Jenkins by setting it in the Global Properties section in the master config:

`"-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1"`

I can echo the variable ${ANT_OPTS} in a 'execute shell' step in the job and in prints to the console correctly, but the changes are not picked up when the job runs.

If I add this to the Java Options section under the Ant config in the job the build works fine.

I'd rather set this globally since I will need it for 300+ jobs - am I doing this incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason that you have to set this ANT_OPTS in Jenkins, instead of directly setting it as a system env variable?

Comment: Mainly because we have 20+ slaves I would need to set it on - would be easier to just set it in one place vs. all systems.

Comment: Oh I see... So you may need to update your question to stress "set once on master, applies on all slaves". Also did a search, seems that you need to set them for each of your slaves in "nodes>"slave_name">Configure"...

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins, go to `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties`.  Check the box for `Environment Variables`, click `Add`, and drop in whatever key-value pair you need.

Comment: Hi David, that is what I originally did, but it is not working.